# This class that should return my location and actually returns 0.0 0.0

Tags: android, google-maps, location

```
public class MyLocation  {
Context mContext;
LocationManager mlocManager;
LocationListener mlocListener;
double  lat=0,lng=0;

public MyLocation(Context mContext) {

    super();
    this.mContext = mContext;
    mlocManager = (LocationManager)mContext.getSystemService(mContext.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    mlocListener = new MyLocationListener();
    mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates( LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mlocListener);

}
/* Class My Location Listener */
public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {
    private static final int TWO_MINUTES = 1000 * 60 * 2;


    public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
        loc.getLatitude();
        loc.getLongitude();

        String Text = "My current location is: " +"Latitud = " + loc.getLatitude() +"Longitud = " + loc.getLongitude();
    //  Toast.makeText( mContext,Text,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        lat = loc.getLatitude();
        lng = loc.getLongitude();
    }

    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider){
        Toast.makeText(mContext,"Gps Disabled",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
    }

    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider){
        Toast.makeText( mContext," Gps Enabled" ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
  }
}
```

This class is not returning what it should be... my location is always `0.0 0.0` don't know what to do.

I use this class like this

`mylocation = new MyLocation(this);`

I have gps and networking enabled when I start the application so this is not the problem...

Comment: Do you have the correct permissions in your Manifest.xml?

Comment: Have you added permissions to get the user's location? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION and http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION

Comment: If you are using an emulator to test this functionality, it will return 0.0, 0.0.

Comment: I have the permision ok  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"></uses-permission>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" /> 
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

Answer (score 1):

Try going outside (I don't mean this offensively, either).  Sometimes GPS doesn't receive a signal indoors, so you may have to head outside in an open area to get actual data.  If the GPS cannot find a signal, it will return 0.0, 0.0.

**Edit:** Also, I noticed you don't override any of the GPS methods.  Try adding an `@Override` for those (i.e. `onLocationChanged`, `onProviderEnabled`, `onProviderDisabled`, and `onStatusChanged`).  This may help.

**Edit 2:** If this still isn't working, go to your phone's settings, then "Location & Security Settings" (may be named slightly different between devices), and make sure "Use wireless networks" and "Use GPS satellites" are both checked off.

**Edit 3:**
This is all its own class, no errors on @Override:

```
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Comment: If that doesn't work, try the part I just added next to "Edit:".  Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: I actually don't know why I get an error when I try the @Override

Comment: Is it it's own separate class?  See "Edit 3:" for sample code I *just* made that allowed me to use @Override

Comment: Woo!  See if that works now.  If not, see "Edit 2:"  (I apologize for all of the edits!)

Comment: Edit 2 is ok ! and stil not working I have to say that google maps is finding mylocation ok.

Comment: So even with the Override is not working don't worry about the edit thanks for the help